Is it possible to define a Typescript interface that can be iterated over?
In javascript I could define an object and iterate over it using Object.entries like so:
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}

// Expected output:
// "a: somestring"
// "b: 42"

How can I define a typescript interface and use it to declare a typescript object and iterate over it the same way?

The iteration means code execution, it happens at runtime. The types do not exist at runtime.

an interface it just metadata, it does not exist at all when you compile to javascript, so there's nothing for it to loop over.  Plus, you example has a key and a value, an interface does not have any values anyway since it just defines types

It's not possible. See the linked q/a above for more information and workarounds.
